# Use bounties more often

Tags: discussion

If you have reputation to spare, and notice good questions, throw a bounty. It saves the good questions from being lost in the flood. Currently there is only one bounty, which is unusually low activity.

You probably will also eventually earn back your bounty.

Comment: [There](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/29/investor) are [some](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/altruist) badges for that.

Comment: Fwiw _too many_ bounties is also a bad thing; the economics pf the thing leads to a devaluation -- a bounty gets a post much less attention.

Comment: @Manishearth there is not much danger of that happening any time soon, is there?

Comment: @Magpie I know... Just noting a fact. We're not in any danger of coming close to the "too many" threshold either :P